# Can't link to another page with user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want link to another page with my user, but i have an error:

```
RuntimeError in WelcomeController#edit
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

In my current page

```
<%= link_to "edit", welcome_edit_path(@user) %>
```

thi is my controller

```
 def edit
   user = User.find_by_id(@user.id)
 end
```

in my page i want link to

```
<%= user.id %>
```

I know my problem is my @user was nil, but i dont know how to link to another page with my @user
So, please! help me

this my routes file

```
  get "micropost/new"

  get "user/new"
  get "user/saved"

  get "post/new"
  get "post/show"

  get "welcome/index"
  get "welcome/sucess"
  get "welcome/edit"
  root :to => "welcome#index"
  get '/users/:id', :to => 'welcome#sucess', :as => "user"  

  match '/relations', to: 'relation#create', via: 'post'
  match '/relations/:id', to: 'relation#destroy', via: 'delete'
  resources :users
  resources :relations,  only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts

  match '/login', to: 'welcome#create', via: 'post'
  match '/logout' => 'welcome#destroy', as: :logout
  match '/create', to: 'micropost#create', via: 'post'
  match '/signup', to: 'user#signup', via: 'post'
```

Comment: Do you want to edit currently logged in user?

Comment: Not my current_user. It's just one user in my list

Comment: So how do you pass this user's id into the controller?

Comment: I see some tutorial and i think i can get user when i put @user into my link <%= link_to "edit", welcome_edit_path(@user) %> . It may be wrong! but i don't know how to send user into may controller

Comment: It's possible, but only when routes are defined properly and the `@user` instance variable is set in the view where you want to display the link to edit page. Show your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: Ok. Then how do you know the user id on the page where you want your link on?

Comment: Here is my link when i click on :"http://localhost:3000/welcome/edit.10". "10" is my @user.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in `edit` method makes no sense. First thing, you have to define your route properly:

```
get '/welcome/edit/:id', to: 'welcome#edit', as: 'welcome_edit'
```

Then, in the `WelcomeController`:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

and the link to this page:

```
<%= link_to 'edit', welcome_edit_path(@user) %>
```

Comment: I tried it before, but it doesn't work. It said "Couldn't find User without an ID"